# Prevent a .txt file file saving the last line as blank

Tags: excel, vba

This is what I have. When this saves to .txt file I would like for the last line to be the last line of text not the open line below it. Please help! Thank you.

```
Sub ExportColB()
Dim myFileName As String, rng As Range, txt As String
myFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
If myFileName = "" Then Exit Sub
With Range("d3", Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If .Count < 2 Then
        txt = .Value
    Else
        txt = Join(Evaluate("transpose(" & _
        .Address(external:=True) & ")"), vbCrLf)
    End If
End With
Open myFileName For Output As #1
    Print #1, txt
Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: You are adding a vbCrLf to every line of `txt`, including the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this amendment to your code.

```
Print #1, Left(Txt, Len(Txt) - 2)
```

BTW your `.Count` isn't a property or method of the Range object. I wonder why your code doesn't crash on this line. It needs to be reviewed.

Comment: `Rows.count` refers to the Activesheet

Comment: @Storax The default property of the Range object is the `Value` property. Therefore `.Count` can't be interpreted as `.Rows.Count`. I agree that OP probably means Rows.Count but I can't be sure. Therefore I recommend review by him.

Comment: As the code is written in the original post `Rows.count`  refers to `ActiveSheet`. And  the second `.Count` is also correct and is a property of the `Range` object. So I am not sure where you see an error. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.count) for the count property of the range object.

Comment: @Storax - thanks for your help. I have two Macro, one to concatenated and then one to export to .ttxt file. I am using Control buttons to execute the export and another one to clear the cells of the concatenation. II used the method earlier Print #1, txt; and this solved the problem but it is happening again. I also tried Print #1, Left(txt, Len(txt) - 2) but same result. Any ideas?

Comment: Not without further details.

Comment: @Peter Neill As I understand your code it creates a single string from all the column's content, using a Split() function to insert CrLf after every cell. My above suggestion was based on the assumption that somehow an extra CrLf slipped into the string which I tried to remove before writing to the TXT file. Since this doesn't seem to have worked I suggest you examine the `txt` string more closely. You can do that by placing a break on that line and look at the end of that string in the Locals Window or examine it further in the Debug window.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Print #1, txt` to write the file which will always add CRLF to the end of the file try `Print #1, txt;`. Do not fortget the semicolon.

Comment: Did you notice that there is no loop in OP's code? Actually, his construction is quite nice. Take a closer look.

Comment: Yes, I noticed. And OP only wants to remove the last CRLF, at least that is my understanding.